# Ionic.Zip ArgumentException (An item with the same key has already been added)

Tags: c#, io, ionic-zip

I'm using Ionic Zip to zip all folders in a specific folder excluding the backup folder (which created backups goes).

This is my code:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
string mainpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
Directory.GetDirectories(mainpath).Where(d=> !d.ToLower().EndsWith("backup")).ToList()
.ForEach(d=> zip.AddDirectory(d));
```

but after adding some directories, I'm getting the following error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

How is it possible? How can possibly be duplicate names in the folder list in the same parent folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I inspected the exception, it seems that it adds the list of all files to be archived in a dictionary.

I don't know what it uses as a key that can cause this error (might be using the file name as the key and having same name in two different folders can cause it).

**Solution**:
However I found out that `AddDirectory` and `AddFiles` has another overload that accepts directory path in archive. giving each of the directories a unique path in archive solved the problem. in my case I used:

```
    string mainpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
    Directory.GetDirectories(mainpath).Where(d=> !d.ToLower().EndsWith("backup")).ToList()
.ForEach(d=> zip.AddDirectory(d, d.Substring(mainpath.Length)));
```